# How do I install PDT 2.0 in Eclipse Ganymede?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.4, eclipse-pdt, ganymede

I've been trying to install PDT in Eclipse 3.4 for a few hours now and I'm not having any success.

I have a previous installation of the Eclipse for Java EE developers (my main deal) distro and I just want to add the PDT to my install so I can also work on some of my websites in Eclipse.

I've done my best to follow [the instructions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation) at the PDT Wiki and I'm just not having any success.  The specific message that it barks at me when I attempt to select the  **PDT Features** option in the PDT Update Site section of the available software dialog is thus:

```
Cannot complete the request.  See the details.
Cannot find a solution satisfying the following requirements Match[requiredCapability:
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group/
[3.0.1.v200807220139-7R0ELZE8Ks-y8HYiQrw5ftEC3UBF,
3.0.1.v200807220139-7R0ELZE8Ks-y8HYiQrw5ftEC3UBF]].
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of all the plugins that you already have it may be faster and easier to go to [YOXOS](http://www.yoxos.com/ondemand/) and download a new copy of eclipse with all the plugins already loaded. just remember to change your workspace if you do this.

Comment: I'm giving that a try, seems like a pretty handy service.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the PDT plugin. Just follow this guide http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation and ensure you're using the latest PDT version (2). The PDT update site serves the previous stable version.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at lots of guides, but i finaly figured it out on myself:

1. Download Ganyamede SDK
2. Through update manager install Web Developer Tools ( v 3.0.x )
3. Again using update manager instal DLTK version 1.0 or higher
4. manualy download latest integration or nightly od PDT 2.0 and unpack it in eclipse folder
5. and now you should have working PDT 2.0 in ganyamede ;)